# process_vm_writev not able to write to the same address that I was able to read from

Tags: c++, linux, process

I am writing a C++ program in an Ubuntu machine. I am using the function calls `process_vm_readv` and `process_vm_writev` from the `<sys/uio.h>` library to attempt to search for a value in the memory of another process and then write a different value.

I am able to successfully search and find (through the proceess_vm_readv function) the data I want to change. I capture the address that it is at, and I attempt to use the `process_vm_writev` but the return value is -1 and `errno` is set to 14 which stands for `bad address`

Is there any reason I shouldn't be able to write to some memory where I can also read? The data I am looking for is found at address `0x6005df` but I cannot actually start writing data back until `0x601000`.

Comment: Some memory locations, like those that contain code, are read-only. This is perfectly normal.

Comment: Basically the same problem as this guy. https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/write-to-remote-process-4175579796/

The response was that the "page might be protected." So then what is the point of having a process_vm_writev function if you can't write?

Comment: @n.m. ah, well in the process I am intercepting, I created an integer x and assigned it to 0xAABBCCDD. I then searched for that value, found it, and want to change x. The thread I am intercepting simply loops forever printing out the value of the integer x. I want to be able to change the value mid process.

Comment: If you have code that doesn't work, show it (see [mcve]).

Comment: Right now I can't get the code from my VM over to the internet, but I did read this... 

" Linux does not have separate text and data address spaces, so the two requests are currently equivalent."

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_system_calls/ptrace.htm

Comment: This valid note from the ptrace manual has nothing to do whatsoever with the subject at hand. Anyway, no one can tell you what's wrong with your code without seeing said code, but you can `objdump -x` your executable and look in what section `0x6005df` lies.

Comment: @n.m Here is the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46099717/modifying-integer-value-from-another-process-using-process-vm-readv

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem using FUSE where the address of the data is perfectly provided from client using ioctl(... *arg), and so client's data can be read by server using **process_vm_readv()**.

But: **process_vm_writev()** won't change the same memory location (no errors) in the client. However when the client provides a *pointer to pointer* and not only a address-pointer, you CAN change the client's memory. It does not matter if the memory location is in heap or stack.

Also: If you try to write to address just above the address and length provided with ioctl() (the cmd arguments codes type, direction and size of data) then it is OK. Seems that during the ioctl call kernel in some way protects the memory area provided.

Also2: If you make/trick the size of struct/data to transfer be 0, then you are allowed to modify client memory of provided address (ioctl(...arg).

Answer (score 0):

In my case it happened because I misplaced the order of arguments in `process_vm_writev()`: both local and remote IOVs were pointing at stack VMA. Due to ASLR they were slightly different. In the kernel during handling the syscall there is an attempt to extend related VMA - `expand_stack` function. The end result was that the offset between stack address from my process and VMA of the process to which I was writing was larger than the process stack limit and hence `-EFAULT`.