# Modifying integer value from another process using process_vm_readv

Tags: c++, c, linux, process, system-calls

I am using Ubuntu Linux to write two programs. I am attempting to change the value of an integer from another process. My first process (A) is a simple program that loops forever and displays the value to the screen. This program works as intended and simply displays the value -1430532899 (0xAABBCCDD) to the screen.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    //The needle that I am looking for to change from another process
    int x = 0xAABBCCDD;

    //Loop forever printing out the value of x
    int counter = 0;
    while(1==1)
    {
        while(counter<100000000)
        {
            counter++;
        }
        counter = 0;
        printf("%d",x);
        fflush(stdout);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

In a separate terminal, I use the `ps -e` command to list the processes and note the process id for process (A). Next as root use (sudo) I run this next program (B) and enter in the process ID that I noted from process (A).

The program basically searches for the needle which is in memory backwards (DD CC BB AA) find the needle, and takes note of the address. It then goes and tries to write the hex value (0xEEEEEEEE) to that same location, but I get a bad address error when errno is set to `14`. The strange thing is a little later in the address space, I am able to write the values successfully to the address (0x601000) but the address where the needle(0xAABBCCDD) is at 0x6005DF I cannot write there. (But can read obviously because that is where I found the needle)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <string>
#include <errno.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

char getHex(char value);
string printHex(unsigned char* buffer, int length);
int getProcessId();

int main()
{
    //Get the process ID of the process we want to read and write
    int pid = getProcessId();

    //Lists of addresses where we find our needle 0xAABBCCDD and the addresses where we simply cannot read
    vector<long> needleAddresses;
    vector<long> unableToReadAddresses;

    unsigned char buf1[1000];  //buffer used to store memory values read from other process

    //Number of bytes read, also is -1 if an error has occurred
    ssize_t nread;

    //Structures used in the process_vm_readv system call
    struct iovec local[1];
    struct iovec remote[1];
    local[0].iov_base = buf1;
    local[0].iov_len = 1000;
    remote[0].iov_base = (void * ) 0x00000;     //start at address 0 and work up
    remote[0].iov_len = 1000;

    for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        nread = process_vm_readv(pid, local, 1, remote, 1 ,0);

        if(nread == -1)
        {
            //errno is 14 then the problem is "bad address" 
            if(errno == 14)
                unableToReadAddresses.push_back((long)remote[0].iov_base);
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<printHex(buf1,local[0].iov_len);

            for(int j=0;j<1000-3;j++)
            {

                if(buf1[j] == 0xDD && buf1[j+1] == 0xCC && buf1[j+2] == 0xBB && buf1[j+3] == 0xAA)
                {       
                    needleAddresses.push_back((long)(remote[0].iov_base+j));
                }
            }

        }
        remote[0].iov_base += 1000;
    }



    cout<<"Addresses found at...";
    for(int i=0;i<needleAddresses.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<needleAddresses[i]<<endl;
    }

    //How many bytes written
    int nwrite = 0;

    struct iovec local2[1];
    struct iovec remote2[1];

    unsigned char data[] = {0xEE,0xEE,0xEE,0xEE};

    local2[0].iov_base = data;
    local2[0].iov_len = 4;
    remote2[0].iov_base = (void*)0x601000;
    remote2[0].iov_len = 4;

    for(int i=0;i<needleAddresses.size();i++)
    {
        cout<<"Attempting to write "<<printHex(data,4)<<" to address "<<needleAddresses[i]<<endl;
        remote2[0].iov_base = (void*)needleAddresses[i];

        nwrite = process_vm_writev(pid,local2,1,remote2,1,0);

        if(nwrite == -1)
        {
            cout<<"Error writing to "<<needleAddresses[i]<<endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout<<"Successfully wrote data";
        }
    }


    //For some reason THIS will work
    remote2[0].iov_base = (void*)0x601000;  
    nwrite = process_vm_writev(pid,local2,1,remote2,1,0);

    cout<<"Wrote "<<nwrite<<" Bytes to the address "<<0x601000 <<" "<<errno;

    return 0;
}

string printHex(unsigned char* buffer, int length)
{
    string retval;
    char temp;

    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
    {

        temp = buffer[i];
        temp = temp>>4;
        temp = temp & 0x0F;
        retval += getHex(temp);

        temp = buffer[i];
        temp = temp & 0x0F;
        retval += getHex(temp);

        retval += ' ';
    }

    return retval;
}

char getHex(char value)
{
    if(value < 10)
    {
        return value+'0';
    }   
    else
    {
        value = value - 10;
        return value+'A';
    }
}

int getProcessId()
{
    int data = 0;
    printf("Please enter the process id...");
    scanf("%d",&data);
    return data;
}
```

Bottom line is that I cannot modify the repeating printed integer from another process.

Answer (score 2):

I can see at least these problems.

1. No one guarantees there's 0xAABBCCDD anywhere in the writable memory of the process. The compiler can optimize it away entirely, or put in in a register. One way to enssure a variable will be placed in the main memory is to declare it `volatile`.

   ```
   volatile int x = 0xAABBCCDDEE;
   ```
2. No one guarantees there's **no** 0xAABBCCDD somewhere in the **read-only** memory of the process. On the contrary, one could be quite certain there is in fact such a value there. Where else could the program possibly obtain it to initialise the variable? The initialisation probably translates to an assembly instruction similar to this

   ```
   mov eax, 0xAABBCCDD
   ```

   which, unsurprisingly, contains a bit pattern that matches 0xAABBCCDD. The address 0x6005DF could well be in the .text section. It is extremely unlikely it is on the stack, because stack addresses are typically close to the top of the address space.
3. The address space of a 64-bit process is huge. There is no hope to traverse it all in a reasonable amount of time. One needs to limit the range of addresses somehow.